# Qt Symbian Fonts

Tags: qt, fonts, symbian, qml, ovi

I have created a Qt app for the Nokia Ovi store but I know want to update the font int the QML file, but just changing it in the designer doesn't change it on the symbian device. I have checked google but nothing I can find looks right. If it helps the font I want to use is Kristen ITC but it might change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a custom font, you'll need to deploy that font along with your application. [This blog article](http://juhaturunen.com/blog/2010/12/using-custom-fonts-on-qtsymbian/) should help you out, though I don't use Symbian so perhaps another answer can go into more detail.

Once font is available on the device, you'll need to add it to your application using [`QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont).

You'll also want to look into licensing whichever custom fonts you deploy with your app. Kristen ITC, for example, is [included with Microsoft products](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?fmid=991), but [licensed by the Monotype Corporation](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=191567).

Comment: I can use the Kristen ITC font with my app on PC but when I run on symbian it doesn't use the font?

Comment: Yes, because the file containing the 'images' for the Kristen ITC font characters is present on Windows but is not on the Symbian device, hence why you need to explicitly include the font file with your application.